# findMeetingTimes returns no results with an empty reason of Unknown

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

The MS Graph API command findMeetingTimes will often return no `MeetingSuggestions` with the empty reason of `Unknown` when I believe there should be a result. I would like to learn more about what generates an Unknown result and whether or not I am using findMeetingTimes correctly.

My request is simple, findMeetingTimes that are an hour in duration from 9:30am to 11:30am where the organizer is optional and the minimum attendee percentage is set to 0%.  I feel I should always get some results in this scenario, but am finding out that I keep getting nothing because of Unknown.  Any help on what causes this?

**Request**:

```
{
  "timeConstraint": {
  "timeslots": [
   {
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2018-05-24T09:30:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2018-05-24T11:30:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    }
  }]
},
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H",
  "isOrganizerOptional": true,
  "minimumAttendeePercentage": 0,
}
```

**Returns**

```
{
  "emptySuggestionsReason": "Unknown",
  "meetingTimeSuggestions": []
}
```

**Notes**: I am busy during this time and so is the one attendee I added as part of the request

Answer (score 0):

Create the JSON object to have the attendees exist, but you can leave it empty

```
"attendees": [
],
```

I run the following and everything works fine:

```
{
  "attendees": [
  ],
  "timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2018-06-25T12:45:00.000Z",
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2018-06-25T22:39:07.097Z",
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "locationConstraint": {
    "isRequired": "true",
    "suggestLocation": "true",
    "locations": [

    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT30M",
    "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
  "maxCandidates": "4",
    "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem is I want to know the free/busy status of the requested attendees.  So if a meeting is conflicted during a certain time, I want to be able to determine if the organizer is busy and/or which attendee cannot make it at that time.   With this suggestion, I lose that information.

Comment: Have you had any luck finding what causes "Unknown" responses?